# Get parameter in expression language

Tags: jsp, parameters, el

How do I get a parameter in el?
I have

```
<select id="odd">
...
</select>
```

I would like to get the selected value in this dropdown menu. And I would like to do it in Expression language.

```
<c:out value="${param.odd}"/>
```

I tried this but nothing happens, what Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="odd">
```

It's the name that is used by the browser as parameter name, not the ID.